# ORACLE SQL: How to Select Max with an INNER JOIN clause and multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below code that I have written already.  There is a date Field Called `EFF_DATE` in the `EMPLOYEE_EFF_DATE` table (eed).  Each record that appears in the SELECT query below needs to pull the data with the Max `EFF_DATE` from that table.

```
 SELECT 
     cd.CODE AS "OrganizationName"
     ,'Subscriber' as ContactType
     ,eed.LAST_NAME as LastName
     ,eed.FIRST_NAME as FirstName
     ,eed.MIDDLE_INIT MiddleName
     ,'' as PrefixName
     ,'' as SuffixName
     ,cs.REAL_SSN as SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
     ,'' as EmployeeNumber
     ,'' as EmployeeType
     ,eed.Latest_hire_date as EmployeeHireDate
     ,cs.REAL_SSN as MemberSocialSecurityNumber
     ,aed.Address_1 as AddressLine1
     ,aed.Address_2 as AddressLine2
     ,aed.City
     ,aed.State
     ,aed.Zip as ZipCode
     ,aed.Country as CountryCode
     ,eed.BIRTHDATE as MemberDOB
     ,eed.SEX as MemberGender
     ,'' as MemberLanguage
     ,'' as MedicalPlan
     ,'' as MemberIDforMedicalPlan
     ,'' as DentalPlan
     ,'' as GeneralPurpose1
     ,'' as GeneralPurpose3
     ,aed.Telephone as HomeNumber
     ,'' as WorkNumber
     ,eed.EMAIL_ADDRESS as WorkEmailAddress
     ,'' as HomeEmailAddress
     ,'' as LocationCode
     ,'' as DashboardDrillDown
     ,'' as VisionPlan
     ,'' as RxPlan
     ,'' as MedicalTierLevelCoverage


 FROM

 EMPLOYEE_EFF_DATE eed

 INNER JOIN ADDRESS_EFF_DATE aed 
     ON eed.ssn = aed.ssn INNER JOIN COMP_SSN cs
     ON cs.ssn = eed.ssn INNER JOIN COMPANY_DETAIL cd
     ON eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = cd.COMPANY_ID INNER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYMENT_DATA ced
     ON eed.SSN = ced.SSN 

     WHERE eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 114562164 
     AND aed.ADDRESS_KEY = 0 
     AND WORKMANS_COMP_EFF_DATE is NULL
     AND ced.STATUS_CODE in ('FTDM','FTREG','PTREG') 
     AND ced.DERIVED_FACTOR_1 in ('NA', 'N/A')
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: Analytic functions: max() over()? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions098.htm#SQLRF00666. For example,  you can add this column to your query: `MAX(eed.EFF_DATE) OVER() as MAX_EFF_DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Derived tables are way to go.. Replace ALL_FIELDS_IN_DT with your actual fields:

```
Select *ALL_FIELDS_IN_DT*, max(EFF_DATE)
FROM 
(
SELECT 
     cd.CODE AS "OrganizationName"
     ,'Subscriber' as ContactType
     ,eed.LAST_NAME as LastName
     ,eed.FIRST_NAME as FirstName
     ,eed.MIDDLE_INIT MiddleName,
     ,eed.EFF_DATE EFF_DATE,
     ,'' as PrefixName
     ,'' as SuffixName
     ,cs.REAL_SSN as SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
     ,'' as EmployeeNumber
     ,'' as EmployeeType
     ,eed.Latest_hire_date as EmployeeHireDate
     ,cs.REAL_SSN as MemberSocialSecurityNumber
     ,aed.Address_1 as AddressLine1
     ,aed.Address_2 as AddressLine2
     ,aed.City
     ,aed.State
     ,aed.Zip as ZipCode
     ,aed.Country as CountryCode
     ,eed.BIRTHDATE as MemberDOB
     ,eed.SEX as MemberGender
     ,'' as MemberLanguage
     ,'' as MedicalPlan
     ,'' as MemberIDforMedicalPlan
     ,'' as DentalPlan
     ,'' as GeneralPurpose1
     ,'' as GeneralPurpose3
     ,aed.Telephone as HomeNumber
     ,'' as WorkNumber
     ,eed.EMAIL_ADDRESS as WorkEmailAddress
     ,'' as HomeEmailAddress
     ,'' as LocationCode
     ,'' as DashboardDrillDown
     ,'' as VisionPlan
     ,'' as RxPlan
     ,'' as MedicalTierLevelCoverage


 FROM

 EMPLOYEE_EFF_DATE eed

 INNER JOIN ADDRESS_EFF_DATE aed 
     ON eed.ssn = aed.ssn INNER JOIN COMP_SSN cs
     ON cs.ssn = eed.ssn INNER JOIN COMPANY_DETAIL cd
     ON eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = cd.COMPANY_ID INNER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYMENT_DATA ced
     ON eed.SSN = ced.SSN 

     WHERE eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 114562164 
     AND aed.ADDRESS_KEY = 0 
     AND WORKMANS_COMP_EFF_DATE is NULL
     AND ced.STATUS_CODE in ('FTDM','FTREG','PTREG') 
     AND ced.DERIVED_FACTOR_1 in ('NA', 'N/A')
) AS DT
GROUP BY *ALL_FIELDS_IN_DT*
```